# Unzipping a folder of JSONs in React and parse them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jszip

what the title says. I'm trying to make an app in React where a user can upload a zip file that is a folder which contains JSONs, and then I want to parse the JSONs to return statistics about their contents. I'm not getting any errors, but I know that the data is never being passed as JSONs to the functions meant to provide statistics.

This is the file reader

```
<ReactFileReader
          multipleFiles={true}
          fileTypes={[".json", ".zip"]}
          handleFiles={this.handleFiles}
        >
          <button
            className="btn"
            style={{
              width: 150,
              height: 50,
              borderColor: "black",
              padding: 5,
              backgroundColor: "#DEDEDE",
              borderRadius: 5
            }}
          >
            Upload
          </button>
        </ReactFileReader>
```

This is my handlefiles function.

```
handleFiles = files => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = e => {
      // Use reader.result
      this.setState({
       // jsonData: JSON.parse(reader.result),
        folder: JSZip.loadAsync(reader.result).then
        (function(zip)
        {
          zip.forEach(zip)
          (
            function(relativePath, zipEntry)
            {
              data.push(JSON.parse(relativePath));
            }
          )
        })
      });
    };
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
      reader.readAsText(files[i]); 
    }
  }; 
}
```

and this this my stats function

```
function stats(data)
{
  if(data)
  {
    var rtrn;
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
      rtrn += streamingHistory(data[i]);
      rtrn += top10(data[i]);
      rtrn += yourLibrary(data[i]);
      rtrn += playlists(data[i]); 
      rtrn += searchQueries(data[i]);
      rtrn += user_data(data[i]);
      rtrn += follow(data[i]);
      rtrn += payments(data[i]);
    <br />
    rtrn += collapseTable(data[i]);
    }
    return <div> {rtrn} </div>;
  }
}
```

All of the functions referenced in stats definitely work, and display the what they're meant to when directly passed a JSON. Any help you could give about how I'm misusing JSZip or potentially handling my files wrong would be much appreciated! I am new to JS/React and still learning

Answer (score 0):

The culprit seems to be this code:

```js
          zip.forEach(zip)
          (
            function(relativePath, zipEntry)
            {
              data.push(JSON.parse(relativePath));
            }
          )
```

This calls `zip.forEach(zip)`, discards the result, and then defines a function that is never called. Instead, you probably meant the following:

```js
          zip.forEach(
            function(relativePath, zipEntry)
            {
              data.push(JSON.parse(relativePath));
            }
          )
```